# TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

What is wrong with my code? I trying to do a search on product.pricelist and find all pricelists with priority boolean checked.

```py
class ProductPricelist(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.pricelist'

    priority = fields.Boolean('Priority')


pricelists = self.env['product.pricelist'].search(['priority', '=', True])

TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Could you add the whole error stacktrace? I don't think the error comes from this one line you've provided.

Comment: I found out why. needed ([('priority', '=', True)])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. You should have your search argument as a list of tuples.

```
pricelists = self.env['product.pricelist'].search([('priority', '=', True)])
```